# Theoretical Results for MICE Imputation

Tags: multivariate-analysis, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

Is there any literature exploring convergence guarantees of the MICE imputation method for missing data? In practice, the method seems to work pretty reliably with different regressor but I can't seem to find any theoretical justification for its relatively good performance / datasets on which it is likely to fail.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Doc Stories. Is you question about convergence of **multiple** imputations under MICE to unbiased estimates, or about convergence of iterations to stable estimates **within each single imputation** under MICE?

Comment: @Alexis the question was in reference to multiple imputations, however a theoretical treatment of either result would be interesting